Is it allowed to return a dereferenced pointer of a blittable struct in C#
Is it possible/allowed to return a dereferenced pointer of an struct from C# pinvoke code like that.
The struct is blittable. The Pinvoke code and the struct are generated with CsWin32. Thanks for any help related to that :)
  internal static unsafe IEnumerable<ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESSW> GetAllServices(this CloseServiceHandleSafeHandle serviceManagerHandle, string? group)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(serviceManagerHandle);

        var data = new List<ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESSW>();
        var serviceManagerHandleAddRef = false;
        try
        {
            serviceManagerHandle.DangerousAddRef(ref serviceManagerHandleAddRef);

            bool moreData;
            uint bytesNeeded = 0, resumeHandle = 0, servicesReturned = 0;
            do
            {
                moreData = false;
                var bufferData = new byte[bytesNeeded];
                fixed (byte* ptrBufferData = bufferData)
                {
                    fixed (char* ptrGroup = group)
                    {
                        if (!PInvokeCore.EnumServicesStatusEx((SC_HANDLE)serviceManagerHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), SC_ENUM_TYPE.SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO, ENUM_SERVICE_TYPE.SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, ENUM_SERVICE_STATE.SERVICE_STATE_ALL, ptrBufferData, (uint)bufferData.Length, &bytesNeeded, &servicesReturned, &resumeHandle, ptrGroup))
                        {
                            if (Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError() != (uint)WIN32_ERROR.ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                                throw new Exception($"Could not enumerate services. {Marshal.GetLastPInvokeErrorMessage()}");
                            else
                                moreData = true;
                        }
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < servicesReturned; i++)
                    {
                        ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESSW element = ((ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESSW*)ptrBufferData)[i];
                        data.Add(element);
                    }
                }
            } while (moreData);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serviceManagerHandleAddRef)
                serviceManagerHandle.DangerousRelease();
        }

        return data;
    }

It works but I'm not sure if that is an illegal operation.

Can you be explicit as to exactly which operation you're concerned about? it doesn't look like you're "returning" any pointers here - unless I'm misreading, it looks like you're dereferencing them when adding them to the list, and that's your own buffer, inside a fixed block?

The concern is when bufferData going out of scope does c# knows that there a references to that buffer in form of the list of elements or does the pointer thing makes it impossible for the GC to know that.

((ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESSW*)ptrBufferData) is a dereference, so the data from the pointer is being returned, not the pointer itself. As long as you don't return a pointer type you are OK. Although the loop looks like it will never end, are you sure the logic is correct

@Charlieface that's not a dereference (without a leading *) - it is just a cast; the [i] is the dereference here; so yes, there is a dereference - it just isn't in the bit you said

@Charlieface The loop is perfectly fine (and working xD ) and for me this is the only way to doing that properly, because a new service could be added between function calls. This is why there is resume handle in the function call.

The answer is no it is not save to return the struct. The struct itself is a copy so it it safe to return but in the struct is a PWSTR aka a char* and that pointer points to an area in the byte* (just after the array of structs) which is not valid after the function returns.
